# Testing rx with 'real' delay

Tags: c#, testing, system.reactive

I have been investigating the possibility of 'protecting' an observable source from a slow observer, by throwing away any new items that come in while the observer is working.

After looking at [`ObserveLatestOn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16638233) (and finding it a bit hard to understand...), I chanced on this answer, which suggested doing it in Subscribe, rather than inside the Observable monad.

Which gives something like this (versions with delegate overloads not shown):

```
public static IDisposable NonBlockingSubscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, 
                                                       IObserver<T> observer)
{
    Task task = null;
    return observable.Subscribe(value =>
    {
        if(task == null || task.IsCompleted)
            task = Task.Run(() => observer.OnNext(value));
    }, observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted);
}
```

The challenge now is working out how to write a test for this using `ReactiveTest` and virtual time.

I've seen the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852061/how-to-use-virtual-time-for-task-run-when-testing-observables-with-reactive-exte) question, which involves using TestScheduler to generate a 'ticker' which can be used in turn to create an AsyncSelector, but I'm a bit stuck working out how to go from there to something which can 'wait for a given number of ticks'.

Comment: What is the question?  Also, you could call `Task.Run(...)` and then call `observer.OnCompleted()` and then have `observer.OnNext(value)` happen because of the `Task.Run(...)`, in that order.  That's a problem.

Comment: @TimothyShields, the question is how I can test this. Good point about the OnCompleted/OnNext race condition, in my particular use case I'm not expecting to ever get an OnCompleted, but it's worth thinking about anyway. I guess I would need to lock `task` and then maybe use ContinueWith.

Comment: Some marble diagrams might be helpful to illustrate the various cases that you want to test for. It's not clear what you're attempting to do.